# Entity state is DETACHED when it should be Modified

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, dbcontext

I am trying to modify data and save changes to my database using `EFCore 3.1.`

but my modifications are not being saved to the database, so after further investigation I found out that after I pull my entity from the context, its state is `DETACHED` instead of `ATTACHED`,
so that's why the changes aren't being saved, because they're not tracked in the first place.

I couldn't figure out why this is happening, I made sure that I did not add `AsNoTracking()` when getting the entity.

Here are my classes and methods:

```
public class UserSettingsDataAccess : IUserSettingsDataAccess

    private readonly NotificationDBContext _context;
    private readonly IReminderDatesDataAccess _reminderDatesDataAccess;


    public UserSettingsDataAccess(NotificationDBContext context, IReminderDatesDataAccess reminderDatesDataAccess)
    {
        _context = context;
        _reminderDatesDataAccess = reminderDatesDataAccess;
    }

    public bool ToggleRemindersForAppointmentAsync(int appointment_id)
            {
                Appointments appointment =  _appointmentDataAccess.GetByIdWithReminders(appointment_id);
                if (appointment == null || appointment.Reminders == null)
                    return bool.Parse(null);
                var x = _context.Entry(appointment).State;
                appointment.Reminders.IsActive = !appointment.Reminders.IsActive;
                var y = _context.Entry(appointment).State;
                 _context.SaveChanges();
                var z = _context.Entry(appointment).State;
                return appointment.Reminders.IsActive.Value;
            }
//rest of code is omitted for brevity
}
```

This one uses another method to get the appointment, toggle its reminder , save changes and return the new reminder state. all of `x`,`y`,`z` variables have `DETACHED` value . when debugging

Here's the second class that contains the method that brings the appointment :

```
public class AppointmentDataAccess: IAppointmentDataAccess
    {
        private readonly NotificationDBContext _context;

        public ReminderDatesDataAccess(NotificationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
public Appointments GetByIdWithReminders(int appointment_id)
        {
            return _context.Appointments.Where(a => a.Id == appointment_id && a.DeletedAt == null)
                .Include(a=>a.Reminders).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
```

`Startup.cs` :

```
services.AddDbContext<NotificationDBContext>(options => options
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"))
            , ServiceLifetime.Transient,ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

and `IUserSettingsDataAccess`, `IAppointmentDataAccess` are just interfaces.

Can anyone point out why this is happening? and how to fix it? it's been driving me crazy for a good couple of hours . TIA!

Comment: Suspect that `_context` in first method is not the same object as `_context` in the second method, so when asking `_context` in the first method for entity state that context does not have it being tracked.  The tracking is done by the context, not by the entity itself.

Comment: @NeilW hmm.. what could cause that? I mean how could that happen? I've done operations like this a thousand times in this project, and this has never happened before.

Comment: Where is `_context` variable declared in `_appointmentDataAccess` class that hosts the `GetByIdWithReminders` method?  Where is `_context` variable declared that is used by `ToggleRemindersForAppointmentAsync`?  And where is each instantiated?

Comment: just a sec, I'll update my question.

Comment: Check `context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior` property. Looks like it is set to a non default value by some code not shown here. So either set it to the default value `TrackAll`, or add `AsTracking()` to `GetByIdWithReminders` implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev The above methods `ToggleRemindersForAppointmentAsync` and `GetByIdWithReminders` are not in the same class.  My guess is each class has its own instantiation of a context.

Comment: Thanks for the question edit.  The Context is being registered as "Transient", so each class is getting their own instance of NotificationDbContext.  That's the problem.  If you're going to use a DataAccess class then let that be the only class that holds a reference to a Context.  Then put a SaveChanges method on that DataAccess class, which can then call SaveChanges on the original DbContext.

Comment: And from an architectural point of view, each DataAccess class should only be managing data within its own scope.  You're trying to manage AppointmentData from UserSettingsData which is a bit smelly.  Best to create a service layer above that uses both dataaccess classes and coordinates activilty across both, instead of one dataaccess class trying to work directly with another.

Comment: @NeilW , thanks a lot for the comments and explanation. about your first comment, I understand what you said about the context being transient, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my situation since the method from the first class is just returning data, no place for `SavChanges()` . and your second point makes a lot of sense , and I see now how that is incorrect.

Comment: @AtaaAub When you call `GetByIdWithReminders` in the `AppointmentDataAccess` Class then it does not JUST return data.  It uses the local `_context` to retrieve the data and then THAT `_context` keeps track of any changes.  So, if you add a `SaveChanges` method to your `AppointmentDataAccess` class, which then calls `SaveChanges` on the ORIGINAL `_context` then that context will be aware of changes and save appropriately.  Calling `SaveChanges` on another `_context` won't work because that other `_context` is not tracking the changes in the first place.

Comment: To summarise, a data entity has no idea whether it has changed or not.  It is always the DbContext class that retrieved that data entity, which keeps a record of what has changed.  Unless you get fancy and start manually telling another DbContext whether an item's state is `modified`, but wouldn't recommend that in this scenario.

Comment: aha. didn't know that! thanks a lot for explaining it! much appreciated!